# Check constraint that checks another column value

Tags: sql

I searched but everything I found either didn't answer the question, or I didn't really understand

I'm creating a table, and I want to put contraints in on some columns that will require it to be not null if another column has a certain value. What I have now is:

```
ColumnA NOT NULL CHECK (ColumnB = 8802 or ColumnB = 8804),
```

Basically if `ColumnB` is equal to either of those two values, `ColumnA` must have a value, and it can be null the rest of time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT A_B_Check
CHECK (
        ColumnA IS NOT NULL 
    OR (ColumnA IS NULL AND (ColumnB <> 8802 AND ColumnB <> 8804))
);
```

Comment: That looks good I think, unfortunately though, I don't have the ability to actually run to see at the moment. I do have one or two questions though. Your first clause no the check, is to see if columnA is null. If Column A hold a value, regardless of the value of ColumnB, will that check clause be satisfied? And the other question is ColumnB <> 8802 AND ColumnB <>8804. Does that mean that columnB needs to be equal to 8802 and 8804? Should I replace the AND with OR, or can I use brackets in the clause to show what I want to be dont first?

Comment: Note that i have just added brackets around the second condition. Since Im currently on a phone it's difficult to explain.